# Distributing randomly generated numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel, I'd like to generate a random binary number (`0` or `1`) six times and then they are to be distributed over six cells, but with some restrictions:

There can be a maximum of three `1`s and three `0`s in these six cells, but each cell should get its value at random, at least until the restrictions are met.

I know it can be done with some ugly if/else stuff, but I wonder if there is a good function for this sort of thing?

Comment: Maximum of three 1's and 0's? When there are exactly 6 slots? Don't you mean that there should be three 1's and three 0's, but distributed randomly?

Comment: As I'm thinking, there might not be a relatively easy solution. `Rnd` function returns just one value. In your case you would need to retrieve 3 random values out of 6 (those would become 1's, others could be 0's). For retrieving more than one random value from a specified range (6) both, with repetition and without (you need without), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753063/excel-macro-random-selection-from-list) answer might be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We create a small table of three **1**'s and three **0**'s and then arrange to sample them in random order.

We put 1 in **E1, E2, E3** and 0 in **E4, E5, E6**
We put :

```
=RAND()
```

in **D1** through **D6**

Finally in **A1** the formula:

```
=INDEX($E$1:$E$6,MATCH(SMALL($D$1:$D$6,ROWS($1:1)),$D$1:$D$6,0))
```

and copy this down through **A6**

*Column **A** has the values appearing in column **E** gathered in random order:*

[image]

Each time the worksheet is re-calculated, the values in column **D** change and the values in column **A** re-arrange.