# Random Sampling & Selection by Category VBA

Tags: vba, excel, random

I am trying to write a macro on MS Excel, which will enable me to create random samples and pick random values from those samples for each category in the data.

To be more specific, the data is at 2 levels: firm and year, where each row represents a firm-year-peer observation. For each firm i, at a given year j, we have number of actual peers.

What I want to do is assign to each firm, from the whole sample throughout many years, a random firm from the list of all available firms at that specific year. The trick is that the number of firms to be assigned should be identical to the number of actual peers that a firm has at that year. Also, the randomly assigned values should be different from the firm's actual peers, and of course, the firm itself.

```
i           j            k
1           2006        100
1           2006        105
1           2006        110
2           2006        113
2           2006        155
2           2006        200
2           2006        300
```

For example, Firm 1's actual peers in year 2006 are 100, 105 and 110. However, all possible firms available are 100, 105, 110, 113, 155, 200 and 300. This means that I have to select 3 (because Firm 1 has 3 actual peers) random fictional peers from the 4 firms that are not Firm 1's peer that year (i.e. 113, 155, 200 and 300). Applying the same procedure for Firm 2, I need to select 4 random firms that are not Firm 2's actual peers from all possible firms.

I hope this was clear.

I started trying this function out on MS Excel, but I am open to suggestions if you think other platforms would be more useful.

Your help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Have you built any VBA code we can help you with?

Comment: Further clarifying your logic, in 2006, Firm 2 has 4 peers. There are 7 total peer firms in 2006. But I need to exclude the ones Firm 2 actually had, so I need to randomly pick 4 firms from (7-4=3) 3 firms. How is that handled? Similarly - is this a pick and replace problem, or a pick and exclude problem? e.g. choose (1 from 4, 1 from 4, 1 from 4) or choose (1 from 4, 1 from 3, 1 from 2)?

Comment: Hi! Many thanks for your comment! I have tried patching some codes I have found inline but so far I have nothing concrete to put here. In the case of Firm 2, it shouldn't be a problem in the actual sample, since it is sufficiently large. Finally, yes, this is a pick and exclude problem, ideally all randomly assigned values should be different. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many thanks to everyone who has visited my post.

After some initial struggling, I have managed to figure out the code myself. I am posting it below for anyone who might need it.

Basically I used the randomisation code posted by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753063/random-selection-from-list) gentle soul, and enhanced it for my needs using couple of flags for each new firm and each new year. Hope it is clear for everyone.

Best

```
    Sub Random_Sampling()
    '
    Dim PeerCount, FirmCount, YearCount As Long
    Dim Focal_CIK, fiscalYear As Long
    Const nItemsTotal As Long = 1532
    Dim rngList As Range
    Dim FirmYearRange As Range
    Dim FirmStart, FirmStartRow, YearStartRow As Long
    Dim ExistingPeers As Range
    Dim idx() As Long
    Dim varRandomItems() As Variant
    Dim i, j, k, m, n As Long
    Dim iCntr, jCntr As Long
    Dim booIndexIsUnique As Boolean

    Set rngList = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Resize(nItemsTotal, 1)

    FirmCount = Cells(2, 10).Value

For k = 1 To FirmCount

    FirmStart = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(k, Columns("E"), 0)
    Focal_CIK = Cells(FirmStart, 1).Value
    YearCount = Cells(FirmStart, 7).Value

  For m = 1 To YearCount

    Set FirmYearRange = Range("H" & FirmStart & ":H200000")
    YearStartRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(m, FirmYearRange, 0) + FirmStart - 1
    fiscalYear = Cells(YearStartRow, 3).Value
    PeerCount = Cells(YearStartRow, 9).Value
    Set ExistingPeers = Range(Cells(YearStartRow + PeerCount, 2), Cells(YearStartRow + PeerCount, 2))

    ReDim idx(1 To PeerCount)
    ReDim varRandomItems(1 To PeerCount)

    For i = 1 To PeerCount

        Do
            booIndexIsUnique = True ' Innoncent until proven guilty

            idx(i) = Int(nItemsTotal * Rnd + 1)

            For j = 1 To i - 1
                If idx(i) = idx(j) Then 'Is already picked
                     ElseIf idx(i) = Focal_CIK Then 'Is the firm itself
                        booIndexIsUnique = False 'If true, don't pick it
                    Exit For
                End If

                For n = 1 To PeerCount
                   If idx(i) = Cells(YearStartRow + n - 1, 2).Value Then 'Is one of the actual peers
                        booIndexIsUnique = False 'If true, don't pick it
                   Exit For
                  Exit For
                End If
               Next n
            Next j
            If booIndexIsUnique = True Then
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop

        varRandomItems(i) = rngList.Cells(idx(i), 1)

        Rows(YearStartRow + PeerCount).EntireRow.Insert

        'The order of the columns are very important for the following lines
        Cells(YearStartRow + PeerCount, 1) = Focal_CIK
        Cells(YearStartRow + PeerCount, 2) = varRandomItems(i)
        Cells(YearStartRow + PeerCount, 3) = fiscalYear
        Cells(YearStartRow + PeerCount, 4) = "0"

    Next i

   Next m

Next k

End Sub
```